# URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier never returns on iPad Air 2 running iOS 8.1

Tags: sqlite, core-data, icloud

I have a new iPad Air 2 running iOS 8.1 that I am using to test my app.

The call to URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier never returns.

I installed iOS 8.1 on my iPhone 5s and everything works as expected.

I am thinking there may be a bug in iOS 8.1 for the iPad Air 2 but I am not sure. I noticed that in Settings for iCloud that Documents and Data wasn't even listed, and I signed out and signed back in and Documents & Data showed up in settings. That leads me to believe that this might be an iOS bug.

But in case it is not, is anyone else had the call to URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier never return? If so, what did you do to fix it?

This is a Core Data app using iCLoud storage for an sqlite data store.

I call ubiquityIdentityToken before and it retuns a non-nil value, so iCloud is available.

```
NSURL *cloudStoreURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:@"XXYYZZ.com.yourcompany.appname"];
```

Answer (score 0):

A user emailed me and said it suddenly started working for him. I just ran my app with no changes and everything works as it should. I do not know why it is working, but something changed somewhere, my guess is Apple changed something.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same issue recently for one of my apps. It never occurred directly for me but it has occurred for Apple during the review process. However, it happened only for one of my apps. A second app with the same code never showed the issue for myself or for Apple. I have contacted DTS regarding the problem. If I get a solution I'll post it here.